# 'ObjectUnsubscribedError object unsubscribed' on valueChanges in custom validator over form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom validation service that I'm using in my form, in case one input depends on another

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup(group, [ServiceValidator.customValidator]);
```

The validator looks similar to this:

```
static customValidator(g: FormGroup) {
    this._unsubscriber$ = new Subject<boolean>();

    g.controls['myControl'].valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscriber$)).subscribe(values => {
       // Logic here
        if (this._unsubscriber$) {
            this._unsubscriber$.next(true);
            this._unsubscriber$.unsubscribe();
        } 
    });
}
```

I noticed that if I change the value to `myControl` input several times, it starts to get slower and slower, although I tried to unsubscribe. When I started using takeUntil, I started to get this error.

My `ServiceValidator` is not a angular component, so I can't use ngOnDestroy.
Also, the `customValidator` gets called whenever a value in the form gets changed.

What am I doing wrong?
How do I safely unsubscribe?

Comment: Question: why are you using `valueChanges` inside custom validator? Seems a bit strange ;)

Comment: there is a logical problem: The validator is called many times. Each time it is called, it will subscribe once more to the valueChanges of the other input. To efficiently unsubscribe, you should not use `this._unsubscriber$` but a local variable `let localUnsubscriber$  = new Subject<boolean>()`, so each subscribtion will be unsubsribed separately....

Comment: But unsubscribiting will only hide the logical problem. You have to find an other way to achieve this. Validating a value depending on a other must be a common thing out there. Try to find it on google (which will redirect to s.o.), and if you don't, ask a new question with this orientation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a takeuntil, you should not use

```
this._unsubscriber$.next(true);
this._unsubscriber$.unsubscribe();
```

but

```
this._unsubscriber$.next(true);
this._unsubscriber$.complete();
```

Comment: thanks, this is the right answer. Do you have any idea why this gets so slow?

Comment: I added a comment to the question ;)